# xcode8 update error; Type (controller) "does not conform to protocol 'WCSessionDelegate'

Tags: compiler-errors, xcode8

After updating to Xcode 8, my controllers with WCSessionDelegate bring the errors on the viewController that type 'does not conform to protocol WCSessionDelegate'.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

Below ViewController: UITableViewController, WCSessionDelegate {

I added;

```
   @available(iOS 9.3, *)
   public func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
       print ("error in sessionDidBecomeInactive")
   }
    public func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
       print ("error in SesssionDidDeactivate")
   }
   public func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith    activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        print ("error in activationDidCompleteWith error")
   }
```

Comment: Inside the `sessionDidDeactivate` function you should call session.activate() (making sure all your other code is ready for the active watch switch)